# Android : Not getting any contacts from contact list

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am fetching contacts successfully by

```
 val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null)
```

but the problem occurs when I don't have any contacts in my contact list and I adding contacts in **google account** from **web end**, after I **sync contact in my phone** from this *xxx@gmail account*, All contacts **display** in my contact list but when I am trying to **fetch contact** then, It **returns 0**.

I don't know what is the problem, there is any other way to fetch this contacts!

If I insert new contact than I got this contact from above **query**, but can't find those contacts which I have added in **web panel** using **google account**.

Help me if you face this type of problem.

I am using this following code to fetch contacts

```
val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null)
    val projection = arrayOf(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID, ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.PHOTO_URI, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE)
    val alContacts = ArrayList<Contact>()
    var mMapContact = JSONObject()
    if (cursor!!.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            val id = cursor!!.getString(cursor!!.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID))
            if (Integer.parseInt(cursor!!.getString(cursor!!.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER))) > 0) {
                val pCur = context.contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, projection, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?", arrayOf<String>(id), ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC")
                var mListMobile = ArrayList<MobileType>()
                var mNameContact = ""
                while (pCur!!.moveToNext()) {
                    val number = pCur.getString(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))
                    mNameContact = pCur!!.getString(pCur!!.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME))
                    val type = pCur.getInt(pCur.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE))
                    when (type) {
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE -> {
                            mListMobile.add(MobileType(number, 0))
                            mMapContact.put(number.replace(Regex(CONTACT_PLUS_PATH_PREFIX), ""), mNameContact)
                        }
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME -> {
                            mListMobile.add(MobileType(number, 1))
                            mMapContact.put(number.replace(Regex(CONTACT_PLUS_PATH_PREFIX), ""), mNameContact)
                        }
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK -> {
                            mListMobile.add(MobileType(number, 2))
                            mMapContact.put(number.replace(Regex(CONTACT_PLUS_PATH_PREFIX), ""), mNameContact)
                        }
                    }
                    /*val contactNumber = pCur!!.getString(pCur!!.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER))
                    val contactName = pCur!!.getString(pCur!!.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME))
                    val contactInfo = ContactInfo(""+id, ""+contactName, "", ""+contactNumber)
                    LogUtil.e(TAG, "getContactList: $contactNumber - $contactName - $id")
                    alContacts.add(contactInfo)
                    break*/
                }
                pCur?.close()
                if(mListMobile.size > 0) {
                    var contact : Contact? = null
                    for (mobile in mListMobile) {
                        contact = Contact(id, "" + mNameContact, ""+mNameContact, false, null, ""+mobile.mobile, "", mobile.type)
                        alContacts.add(contact!!)
                    }
                }
            }
        } while (cursor?.moveToNext())
    }
```

Comment: are you getting those contacts that you added on google account through web panel in your device?

Comment: No, I am not getting that's why I am asking, I am getting those contacts which I have added in Device

Comment: If you are not getting those contacts in your device then your contacts have not synced properly. You will have to sync from the account it manually on Settings.

Comment: I sync properly thats why those contacts display in contact list

Comment: show the full code to fetch contact and which device you are using?

Comment: I updated question plz check, and MI device but device not depend

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185877/discussion-between-rakesh-kumar-and-mohit-suthar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can use like this following:**

```
String[] projection = {
                        ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,
                        ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI,
                        ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED,
                        ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Contactables.DATA,
                        ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Contactables.TYPE
                };



                String selection = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " in (?, ?)" + " AND " +
                        ContactsContract.Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '" + 1 + "'";

                String[] selectionArgs =
                        {
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE,
                        };
                String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.SORT_KEY_ALTERNATIVE;



                Uri uri = null;
                if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
                    uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Contactables.CONTENT_URI;
                }
                else
                {
                    uri = ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI;

                }


                Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);

                final int mimeTypeIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE);
                final int idIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID);
                final int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
                Log.e("Contacts----", "ontacts__nameIdx----" + nameIdx);
                final int dataIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Contactables.DATA);
                final int typeIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Contactables.TYPE);
                final int photo = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Contactables.PHOTO_URI);
                final int account_type = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE);
                sb = new StringBuilder();
                while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                    long id = cursor.getLong(idIdx);

                    int type = cursor.getInt(typeIdx);
                    String data = cursor.getString(dataIdx);
                    String mimeType = cursor.getString(mimeTypeIdx);
                    String photo_uri = cursor.getString(photo);
                    String account_t = cursor.getString(account_type);

                    Log.e("Contacts----", "Contacts__----" + nameIdx+"---"+type+"---"+data+"----"+id);
                    if (mimeType.equals(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)) {

                        /**For email  **/
                        Log.e("Contacts----","Contacts__>>"+type+"---data---"+data+"--id--"+id);

                    } else {
                        //
                        Log.e("Contacts-----","Contacts__else>>"+type+"---data---"+data+"--id--"+id);

                    }
                }

                cursor.close();
```

**Hope It'll help you.**

Comment: @Mohit Suthar, If above solution helped you and solved your problem then mark this answer as correct and upvote it so that it will help to others as well.

Comment: Welcome, I am glad to help you. :)

Answer (score 2):

I resolve my issue from @Rakesh answer for better result in kotlin you can use like this

```
val projection = arrayOf(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_URI, ContactsContract.Contacts.STARRED, ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Contactables.DATA, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Contactables.TYPE)

        val selection = ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE + " in (?, ?)" + " AND " +
                ContactsContract.Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " = '" + 1 + "'"

        val selectionArgs = arrayOf(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)

        val sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.SORT_KEY_ALTERNATIVE

        val uri = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Contactables.CONTENT_URI

        val cursor = context.contentResolver.query(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder)

        val mimeTypeIdx = cursor!!.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE)
        val idIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Data.CONTACT_ID)
        val nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)

        val dataIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Contactables.DATA)
        val typeIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Contactables.TYPE)
        val photo = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Contactables.PHOTO_URI)
        val account_type = cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE)

        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            var mListMobile = ArrayList<MobileType>()

            val id = cursor.getLong(idIdx)
            val type = cursor.getInt(typeIdx)
            val number = cursor.getString(dataIdx)
            val mimeType = cursor.getString(mimeTypeIdx)
            val mNameContact = cursor.getString(nameIdx)
            val photo_uri = cursor.getString(photo)
            val account_t = cursor.getString(account_type)


            when (type) {
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_MOBILE, 0 -> {
                     Log.i(TAG, ""+number) 
                }
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_HOME -> {
                    Log.i(TAG, ""+number) 
                }
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.TYPE_WORK -> {
                    Log.i(TAG, ""+number) 
                }
            }
        }
        cursor.close()
```